# access sparksession from RelationalGroupedDataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A regular spark dataframe allows to access the `sparksession` via `df.sparksession`

```
class RelationalGroupedDataset protected[sql](
    df: DataFrame,
    groupingExprs: Seq[Expression],
    groupType: RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupType) {
```

How can I access the sparksession of a `RelationalGroupedDataset`? It seems to be private only.

My motivation is to get access to spark's implicits without requiring to pass a sparksession around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you depend on having multiple session instances in scope, using `implicit` argument

```
def f(gds: RelationalGroupedDataset)(implicit spark: SparkSession) = ???
```

or using builder

```
def f(gds: RelationalGroupedDataset) = {
  import SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.implicits._
}
```

is usually good enough. If not, you can always use hack like this:

```
def f(gds: RelationalGroupedDataset) = {
  import gds.count.sparkSession.implicits._
}
```

Comment: IS there a way to also access the `df` parameter? In particular I would like to get access to the column names of the grouped data frame.